# bootstrap panel body alignment issue when trying to add "choose file and remove button" upon add button click

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a "choose file button and remove button" upon another add button inside a bootstrap panel body: the add button is working fine, but I am facing issue with newly added row alignment.

This is the bootstrap-panel-alignment:

[image: bootstrap-panel-body-alignment]

This is the body issue:

[image: body issue]

How to fix this issue?

Please find the code I am currently working on.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/uploadAttachementFiles.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="js/uploadAttachementComponent.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uploadAttachementfiles.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="UploadController as vm">


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="desc" class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-form-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-5">
          <textarea class="col-xs-8 col-md-9" rows="3" cols="5" maxlength="255" id="desc" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group  row ">
          <label for="uplodedFiles" class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-form-label">Uploded Files:*</label>
          <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-9 col-md-8">
            <div class="panel-heading">Location</div>
            <div class="panel-body ">
              <div ng-repeat="file in vm.files">
                <button type="button" class="btn col-xs-1 col-form-label" ng-hide="myValue" ng-click="Remove($index)">
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
                                </button>
                <input type="file" value="{{vm.Name}}" id="fg" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="Add()"></span>
              <input type="button" ng-click="Add()" value="Add" ng-model="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var App = angular.module('App', []);
    App.controller('UploadController', ['$scope', function($scope, $window) {
      var file = {};
      $scope.vm.files = [file

      ];
      $scope.Add = function() {
        //Add new item to Array
        var file = {};
        file.Name = $scope.Name;
        $scope.vm.files.push(file);
        //Clear Text boxes
        $scope.Name = "";
        console.log(file);
      };
      $scope.Remove = function(index) {
        //Find the record From Array Using index
        {
          //Remove Item from Array using index
          $scope.vm.files.splice(index, 1);
          console.log(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you could try adding "display: grid;" to the panel-body

Comment: you have add one class  <div class="test" ng-repeat="file in vm.files"> here. and at that class you have to put  css .test { float: left; width: 100%; }

Comment: P.S. also, where is your opening <form> tag?

Comment: Adding "display: grid;" to the panel-body solved my Issue, Thank you Matt :) :)

Comment: Still facing issue in IE11, is there any other changes do i need for making i work in IE

Comment: why are u adding "display: grid;" to panel body? try to use the framework properly, that will avoid all the issues, try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

As answered earlier by others please follow the sanity of code.

The issue which u are facing was this `<div class="panel panel-default col-xs-9 col-md-8">` adding `grid-column(col-xs-9 col-md-8)` classes with `panel`, move column related classes to a div and it will work fine.

please check the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="desc" class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-form-label">Description:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9">
      <textarea class="btn-block" rows="3" cols="5" maxlength="255" id="desc" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="uplodedFiles" class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-form-label">Uploded Files:*</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Location</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div ng-repeat="file in vm.files">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px" ng-hide="myValue" ng-click="Remove($index)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
              </button>
              <input type="file" value="{{vm.Name}}" id="fg" class="pull-left" />
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="Add()"></span>
            <input type="button" ng-click="Add()" value="Add" ng-model="Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Girish, Its working fine with code you added but its placing choose file first and remove button next. But i need remove button first followed by choose file button

Comment: ok, have updated the ui design as per your request in the above snippet :)

Comment: Thank you Girish :)

Comment: Hi Girish, Still facing issue in IE11, is there any other changes do i need for making i work in IE

Comment: please recheck the code, i don't think it will cause any issue in IE, can u share the code or screenshot of it along with the inspector turned on.